# SupportMapFragment is hiding admob banner

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to show admob banner under the Google Maps Fragment, at the bottom of the screen but without covering any part of the map.

I'm currently using LinearLayout but Google Maps Fragment takes all the remaining height of the screen and the AdView is not showing. How to do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/origin_place_autocomplete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/destination_place_autocomplete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXX">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use frameLayout or constraintlayout and also check AdView key is proper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the Map Fragment into a LinearLayout and give that Linear Layout an

```
android:layout_height="0dp"    
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: It works. Can you explain me how this solution (and weight) work?

Comment: Your Map Fragment will attempt to fill all of the available space. This leaves no space left for fragments underneath.

The LinearLayout is effectively acting as a "fill what you can" with what screen space is left.

The Weighting is for if you were to be using more than one element & you wanted to share whats left of the space between them. E.g. 2 elements with the same weight would be given a 50% slice of the space. If you were to weight one element more than the other, they would gain a higher % of whats left. The values dependant on what weight values you provide.